# How to check if a method is available using setinterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

A third-party js library was loading after some time after page load. Basically depends on it I have to call a method of it. The approach is checking the third party method using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` if it's the method (ag) available and then execute. The interval will run up to 10 times on every X second but if the method (ag) is available then stop the interval and execute the custom function.

```
$(document).ready( function () {

 setInterval(function () {
     if (typeof ag != 'undefined') { 
         // ag is available and execute your code here. 
         clearInterval();
     }
 }, 10);

}
```

Are there any better solutions?

**EDIT 1:**

Using above linked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618519/2479903) answer -

```
function whenAvailable(name, callback) {
    var interval = 10; // ms
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if (typeof name != 'undefined') {
            callback();
        } else {
            whenAvailable(name, callback);
        }
    }, interval);
}

whenAvailable("sp", function(t) {
    // do something
});
```

But how to set limits to execute max 10 times?

Comment: Does the library not have some sort of event fired for when it loads?

Comment: Nope no such events

Comment: Maybe tweaking library code to [detect changes in window object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55368754/proxying-window-object-to-detect-changes) would help?

Comment: "10 times on every X second" .... no, 100 times every second

Comment: how is this library loaded? a script tag? script tags have a `load` event  - I dunno - with virtually no information in the question I'm stabbing in the dark

Comment: Yeah it's a script tag

Comment: Well which library is it? Does not not have an FAQ for exactly that?

Comment: I would more interested on custom code rather then finding library options

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. Just clear the interval when ag found or after 10 repetition.

```
var x = 0;
var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof ag != "undefined") {
        console.log('ag loaded!);
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
        // do stuff
    }
    if (++x === 10) {
        console.log('complete 10 times');
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
}, 1000);
```