# Listening to changes made to a variable (for real)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy, observable

I have the following situation:

- I have two Vanilla JS components.
- The first component, `Alpha`, can make changes to a window variable, e.g. `window.App.messages`.
- The second component, `Beta`, needs to execute a given function but only after `window.App.messages` has changed.

We have the following constraints:

- [A] We don't want the two components to communicate to each other in any other way other than through `window`.
- [B] We don't want `Beta` to change `window.App.messages` in any way.
- [C] `window.App.messages` should be agnostic with regards to which component is going to `set` and `get` its data.

I found a number of relevant Stack Overflow threads, but they all seem to suggest solutions that don't actually work to solve this use case. Specifically:

- Use `Proxy` ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759987/listening-for-variable-changes-in-javascript), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020982/how-to-subscribe-to-object-changes)). The problem with `Proxy` is that you then need to listen to changes to the proxy and not the original object. This implementation wouldn't work as it would require `Alpha` and `Beta` to communicate directly. It breaks [A].
- Overwrite `setters` and `getters` via defineProperty ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55368754/proxying-window-object-to-detect-changes)). This solution requires Beta to change the original object and that's not okay. It breaks both [B] and [C].
- Create the object with custom `setters` and `getters`. This too doesn't work since it breaks [C].

What I would need is something like this:

```
var window.App.messages = ["Hello, world!"];

function logChange(variable) {
  console.log(`New value: ${variable.at(-1)}`)
};

var varListener = Listener(window.App.messages, logChange);

window.app.messages.push("The answer is 42.");

>> New value: The answer is 42.
```

Comment: I don't think there's any way to be notified when a variable changes.

Comment: The only thing you could do is "poll" the variable every so often.